# LOTUS for non-continuous funtion

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expected-value, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of **continuous** and **uniformly bounded** functions. Suppose, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ **pointwise** for all $x\in [a,b]$ .

Now, let us take $X\sim \text{Unif}[a,b]$ . Then, as the $f_n$'s are continuous, so by the **Law of the Unconscious Statistician (LOTUS)**, we can say that $$E[f_n(X)]=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f_n(u)~du$$ Also, due to the uniformly bounded criterion, by **DCT**, it can be easily shown that $E[f_n(X)]\longrightarrow E[f(X)]$ .

But the problem is that $f$ is not necessarily a continuous function. So I'm not allowed to use LOTUS on $f$ and write $E[f(X)]$ as a **Riemann Integral**. Can someone please help to resolve this issue **without** using any measure theory arguments ? You may assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable. Thanks in advance.

---

**P.S. :** What I want to show is : $$\int_a^b f_n(t)~dt ~\longrightarrow~\int_a^b f(t)~dt$$ where the integrals are Riemann integrals.

Comment: Wait a minute... You used DCT but don't want to use measure theory arguments? (DCT is  from measure theory (Lebesgue integrals) )

Comment: Yeah. We haven't been taught Measure Theory so far. But this is a problem which I came across.

Comment: So how do you know DCT?